# Image of Morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ not a Closed Point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C$ be a curve over a field $k$ with following properties:

(i) $C$ integral

(ii) There exist a rational point $a \in C$ such that the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{C, a}$ is regular (so the maximal ideal $m_a$ is generated by one element)

(iii) $h^0(\mathcal{O}_C) := dim_k H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C) =1 $ and $h^1(\mathcal{O}_C) := dim_k H^1(C, \mathcal{O}_C) =0 $

By (ii) it's easy to see that the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{O}_C(-a)$ gives rise for an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{O}_C(a)$ (because $m_a = <r>$).

Using (ii) and (iii) it's easy exercise (using kohomology sequences) that $\mathcal{L}$ is globally generated and $h^0(\mathcal{L}) =2$.

According to the correspondence 
$$Hom_{(Sh/k)}(X, \mathbb{P}^1) \to \{(\mathcal{L}, s) | \mathcal{L} \text{ invertible, } s:\mathcal{O}_X ^{\oplus 2} \to \mathcal{L} \text{ surjective} \} / \sim $$

the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ gives rise for a morphism $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ with $\mathcal{L}= f^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$.

Because $C$ irreducible and proper we get that $f(C) \subset \mathbb{P}$ is irreducible closed.

I want to know why $f(C)$ can't be a closed point?

How can I conclude that if $f(C)$ would be one closed point, then this would imply $h^0(\mathcal{L}) = h^0(\mathcal{O}_C)$ (so a contradiction)?

Comment: If $f(C) = p$ is a closed point, then the map $f$ factors as $i \circ \pi : C \to p \to \mathbb{P}^1$ so $\mathcal{L} = f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = \pi^*i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = \pi^*\mathcal{O}_{p} = \mathcal{O}_C$.

Comment: @Dori Bejleri: Thank you for the answer. One step stays unclear to me: Why $i^* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)= \mathcal{O}_p$ holds?

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_p$ is the only line bundle on a point.