# Inverse Image of Tautological Bundle Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $p \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ a closed point of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $i: p \to \mathbb{P}^1$ the canonical closed imbedding. I want to see how to explicitely prove $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = \mathcal{O}_p $.

I tried to start using the general definition of the inverse image presheaf by $U \to i^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)(U) \otimes _{i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(U)} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(U) 
$

Considering $i^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)(V)= \varinjlim _{p \in V \subset \mathbb{P}^1}  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)(V)= \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)_{\mathbb{P}^1, p}$,

as well as $i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(V)= \varinjlim _{p \in V \subset \mathbb{P}^1} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(V) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1, p}$.

so I get $i^{-1} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)(U) \otimes _{i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(U)} \mathcal{O}_{P}(U) =  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)_{\mathbb{P}^1, p} \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1, p}} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(U)$ as presheaf.

But I don't see the why this simplification imply $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) = \mathcal{O}_p $.

The background of the question is here: [Image of Morphism $C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ not a Closed Point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587580)

Comment: $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ is a rank 1 vector bundle... on a point. So it is trivial, and so it is $\mathcal{O}_p$ (this is not $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1,p}$ as you claimed).

Comment: Yes, sorry, $\mathcal{O}_p$ was that what I meant, not the stalk :)

Comment: By the way do you see any possibility to see also this equalitity using "classical" sheaf theoretical methods to verifying the equality on the level of stalks/small enough open sets in similar way - but a bit more sophisticated :) - as I tried it above?

Comment: I am not sure about what you are expecting here. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be any line bundle on any space $X$ and $p$ be any point. In light of my first comment, $i^*\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{O}_p\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}} i^{-1}\mathcal{L}$. But because $\mathcal{L}$ is locally trivial, $i^{-1}\mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to $i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ (compute the direct limit with a system of neighborhoods of $p$ which trivialize $\mathcal{L}$). So in the end $i^*\mathcal{L}\simeq \mathcal{O}_p\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\simeq\mathcal{O}_p$.